# Can this extension of fields be transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be a local integral domain which is contained in a field $K$.  Let $0 \neq x \in K$ be such that $\mathfrak m R[x]$ is a proper ideal of $R[x]$ (one can show for any $x$ that either this holds, or it holds for $x^{-1}$).  Let $\mathscr P$ be a maximal ideal of $R[x]$ containing $\mathfrak m R[x]$.  Then $\mathscr P \cap R$ is a proper ideal of $R$ containing $\mathfrak m$, so $\mathscr P \cap R = \mathfrak m$.  Thus we have an inclusion of fields $$R/\mathfrak m \rightarrow R[x]/\mathscr P$$ I was wondering whether there was a case where this extension of fields is transcendental.  In every example I've tried, it has been algebraic.

I am asking because Serge Lang seems to consider this case in his algebraic geometry book:

[image: scan from Lang's book]

Here $R = \mathcal O$, $F = R/\mathfrak m$, $\mathfrak P = \mathscr P$, and $\sigma$ is the canonical map $R[x] \rightarrow R[x]/\mathscr P$.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{p}$? Do you mean $\mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I missed something, $R[x]/\mathscr{P}$ is generated *as an algebra* over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ by the class $\bar x$ of $x$ (because any element of $R[x]$ is a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $R$, and its class mod $\mathscr{P}$ is therefore a polynomial in $\bar x$ with coefficients in $R/\mathfrak{m}$).  But a field extension which is finitely generated as an algebra [is algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma).

Comment: That's exactly what we were thinking.  But I'm just wondering why Lang would mention the transcendental possibility.

Comment: Maybe Lang didn't want to prove Zariski's lemma at this point. Or maybe it was a mistake (there are known to be a number of them in Lang's books): perhaps he was thinking $\mathfrak{P}$ was just a prime ideal because of the notation.